# Running the JAR on public web

Tags: java, web-services, jar, war

I have created a jar using eclipse. I want to put this jar on my website and want people to use this program over the internet.

Is there a way to make it easy or should I re-code the program as web service?

Comment: Instead of rewriting, You can write a simple jsp which can call the methods of your Jar and expose the functionality.

Comment: Can you please give me a link for sample? I cant find any.

Comment: check answer. posted

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends primarily on what your program (jar) does and how it is structured.

- Is it a pure console application or does it offer a GUI?
- Should the application run on the client or on a server in the future?

In the case of the console application, a web service that accepts requests with or without parameters would probably be the first choice. Then the application runs on the server.

If the application provides a GUI, Java Web Start is one way of using the existing interface unchanged, as already suggested. In this case, the application runs on the client. Alternatively, you could move the application's business core to a new web application that executes code both in the client's browser (JavaScript) and on the server (Java).

Comment: Its a desktop application. It has GUI. I want the program work on explorer but user shouldnt download it.

Comment: I assume that 'Explorer' refers to the browser. The two requirements cannot be combined in this way. Either the existing GUI application is downloaded and executed (this can be simplified by Java Web Start, for example) or the application runs on the server and is displayed in the browser. A new surface must be developed for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, see Java Web Start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Arrays, com.jarpackage.jar" %>

<%
    String param= request.getParameter("paramName"); 

    //if any input is required from user

     JARClassName service= new JARClassName();
     String message = service.JarMethod(param);
     response.setStatus(200);   
     response.getWriter().write(message);
     //writing data back to output.

%>
```

You can write jsp like this , from where you can call method of your JAR and return the output to user.

You can use Get parameters and read using `request.getParameter("paramName")` if any input from user is required.